# How to fit a multimodal log-normal distribution in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, distribution, curve-fitting

I need to fit a multimodal distribution that represent particle size measurements. These measurements could for example look like this:

[image: Particle size]

Now I would like to fit these curves. With the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55478849/3562088) I was able to get quite decent results for a unimodal distribution function:

```
fun = @(p,x)(p(1)./x .* 1./(p(3)*sqrt(2*pi)).*exp(-(log(x)-p(2)).^2./(2*p(3)^2)));
```

by scaling the resulting parameters like this:

```
[yM_in, pp_in] = max(DPF_in_mean);
xM_in = x_data(pp_in);
[yM_out, pp_out] = max(DPF_out_mean);
xM_out = x_data(pp_out);

xR_in = x_data / xM_in;
yR_in = DPF_in_mean / yM_in;
xR_out = x_data / xM_out;
yR_out = DPF_out_mean / yM_out;

opts = optimoptions('lsqcurvefit','TolX',1e-4,'TolFun',1e-8);
p0 = [1,1,1];
p_in = lsqcurvefit(fun,p0,xR_in,yR_in,[],[],opts);
p_out = lsqcurvefit(fun,p0,xR_out,yR_out,[],[],opts);

p_in_scaled = [ yM_in * p_in(1) * xM_in, p_in(2) + log(xM_in), p_in(3) ];
p_out_scaled = [ yM_out * p_out(1) * xM_out, p_out(2) + log(xM_out), p_out(3) ];
```

However if I plot the resulting fit it is obvious that a unimodal distribution is not sufficient to fit the measurements:

[image: Fit with unimodal distribution]

In the Wikipedia article about [multimodal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimodal_distribution) it seems I could just *blend* a second distribution in like this:

```
fun = @(p,x)(p(7)*(p(1)./x .* 1./(p(3)*sqrt(2*pi)).*exp(-(log(x)-p(2)).^2./(2*p(3)^2))) + (1 - p(7))*(p(4)./x .* 1./(p(5)*sqrt(2*pi)).*exp(-(log(x)-p(6)).^2./(2*p(5)^2))));
```

However I don't know how I need to integrate the additional parameters in the scaling

```
p_in_scaled = [ yM_in * p_in(1) * xM_in, p_in(2) + log(xM_in), p_in(3) ];
```

because I didn't really understand what is happening in this scaling step.

How can I use a multimodal distribution to fit my measurements?

**EDIT**

The used data is the following:

```
x_data = [4.87000000000000e-09 5.62000000000000e-09 6.49000000000000e-09 7.50000000000000e-09 8.66000000000000e-09 ...
          1.00000000000000e-08 1.15500000000000e-08 1.33400000000000e-08 1.54000000000000e-08 1.77800000000000e-08 ...
          2.05400000000000e-08 2.37100000000000e-08 2.73800000000000e-08 3.16200000000000e-08 3.65200000000000e-08 ...
          4.21700000000000e-08 4.87000000000000e-08 5.62300000000000e-08 6.49400000000000e-08 7.49900000000000e-08 ...
          8.66000000000000e-08 1.00000000000000e-07 1.15480000000000e-07 1.33350000000000e-07 1.53990000000000e-07 ...
          1.77830000000000e-07 2.05350000000000e-07 2.37140000000000e-07 2.73840000000000e-07 3.16230000000000e-07 ...
          3.65170000000000e-07 4.21700000000000e-07 4.86970000000000e-07 5.62340000000000e-07 6.49380000000000e-07 ...
          7.49890000000000e-07 8.65960000000000e-07 1.00000000000000e-06];

DPF_in_mean = [188318640795.745 360952462222.222 750859638450.704 2226776878843.93 4845941940346.82 7979258430057.80 ...
               11010887350289.0 13462058712138.7 15090350247398.8 15991756383815.0 16680978441618.5 17862081914450.9 ...
               20071390890173.4 23460963364161.9 27630428508670.5 31777265780346.8 35520451433526.0 38587652184971.1 ...
               40516972485549.1 41326812092485.6 41127130682080.9 40038712485549.1 37976259664739.9 34725415132948.0 ...
               30177578265896.0 24546703179190.8 18400851109826.6 12500471611560.7 7540309609248.56 3912091102658.96 ...
               1632974141040.46 458500289086.705 126012891030.303 0 0 0 7276263267.44526 11203995842.0392];

DPF_out_mean = [444898373533.333 1032357396444.44 1675044380444.44 2316141430222.22 2852971589555.56 3151959865111.11 ...
                3134892475777.78 2828026308000.00 2325761940666.67 1745907627777.78 1192912799111.11 742253282222.222 ...
                430349362888.889 255820144555.556 188235813444.444 181970493622.222 204829338533.333 233009821977.778 ...
                243007623333.333 230736732777.778 202426609488.889 169758857200.000 140604138622.222 116482776222.222 ...
                95076737155.5556 74172071777.7778 53672033733.3333 35251323911.1111 20813708255.5556 11102006362.8889 ...
                5497173092.96089 2625918349.76536 1471042995.80373 1012939492.96541 751738952.194595 589422111.731818 ...
                479373451.936508 378359645.767442];
```

Comment: Hi James, not really. I need this to fit measurement as input for a model that I build up as part of my PhD thesis. I have to admit that during my school time we didn't use any Matlab or Python so I am quite surprised by your question. Although if you view a PhD as a very extended school work, it's probably school work...

Comment: Understood. Would you please post either example data or a link to example data?

Comment: Yes! What is the recommended way of providing data files for stackoverflow?

Comment: If the example data set is not large, edit the question and add it as text. If it is large, provide a link to a text file. I think text would be preferred as mostly everyone can read and import text data such as CSV files.

Comment: Is there a preferred hosting site for SO?

Comment: I added the data directly in the question. I think this is the best way to handle data on SO, because otherwise it can't be guaranteed, that the data is available at a later time, right?

Comment: Is the data x, y and z for an equation of the form "z = f(x, y)"? I do not understand the meaning of the variable names.

Comment: The variable `x_data` is the x data for both cases `DPF_in_mean` and `DPF_out_mean`. These are just two independent measurements as shown in the first diagram. Here `DPF_in_mean` corresponds to *Upstream measured* and `DPF_out_mean` corresponds to *Downstream measured*. Then I try to fit both curves with `fun`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possibility that might be of some use. Because the large peaks in the data obscure the smaller peaks, subtracting the larger peak data leaves the small peak data isolated for analysis. If you know the form of the large peak, you can fit the data to that and then have only one of the two bimodal peaks remaining for analysis in each data set. Once you find the form of the second peak, you can the start over by fitting the sum of the two using the previous analysis fitted values as initial parameter values for the final analysis.

I have performed an equation search on both data sets to find a suitable peak equation for the main peaks in each set, here are my results. No data transformation or preconditioning was done and I used the raw data as posted.

For DPF_in_mean I have the main peak as:

[image: in_plot]

```
def Peak_LogNormalAShifted_model(x_in): # from zunzun.com using DPF_in_mean
    # coefficients
    a = 4.2518873952455000E+13
    b = -1.6088042345890798E+01
    c = 6.0084502637701809E-01
    d = -2.3091703726006359E-08

    return a * numpy.exp(-0.5 * numpy.power((numpy.log(x_in-d)-b) / c, 2.0))
```

For DPF_out_mean I have the main peak as:

```
def Peak_LogNormalA_model(x_in): # from zunzun.com using DPF_out_mean
    # coefficients
    a = 3.1863877879345913E+12
    b = -1.8334716040160675E+01
    c = 4.4913908739937525E-01

    return a * numpy.exp(-0.5 * numpy.power((numpy.log(x_in)-b) / c, 2.0))
```

[image: out_plot]

Comment: Hi James, sorry for my late reply. I see that these are the best fits for unimodal distributions, but how could I use a multimodal distribution (i.e. with two or more peaks)?

Comment: The idea is to subtract the main peak equation's predicted values from the observed data, leaving only the secondary peak for analysis. After the second peak's data has been analyzed and a suitable equation found for it, start over by fitting "y = [peak equation main] + [peak equation secondary" using the parameter values from the two separate regressions as the initial parameter values for the final regression analysis.

Comment: Ah now I get it! I will try this today.